Fixing CVE without sudo apt-get upgrade in Ubuntu
For fix CVE-2024-28085 amazon suggests:
Name
util-linux
Installed version / Fixed version
For fix CVE-2024-28085 amazon suggests:

Upgrade your installed software packages to the proposed fixed in version and release.
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade

Why can I not just fix the the package util-linux, but instead should do an update and upgrade of all packages?
Why not just update with
sudo  apt-get install --only-upgrade util-linux


"Why can I not just fix the the package util-linux, but instead should do an update and upgrade of all packages?"  because of dependency hell :+

@user535733 usual method is just updating the package.


Upgrade your installed software packages to the proposed fixed in version and release.
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade

is just a generic notice.

Why can I not just fix the the package util-linux

You can but it is a lot more work and it is less certain to work. The whole idea of update/upgrading all is that this one CVE will not be the only fix and this way you will take care of those too. And it is also a proven method. apt is there to prevent dependency issues.
2 methods:
If you have a .deb you can use dpkg (assuming util-linux-2.40):
 dpkg -i util-linux-2.40.deb

It will not update anything else so if there is a library involved you need to download that too and install it before this one. And check if this affects any other software yourself.
And this will install v2.40 from source
sudo apt-get install gettext bison autopoint -y 
cd ~/Downloads
wget https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/v2.40/util-linux-2.40.tar.gz
tar -xf util-linux-2.40.tar.gz && cd util-linux-2.40
./autogen.sh && ./configure 

and you will have the latest version. This too requires you to fix any other software yourself.
Do make a system backup before you start.
